# How can I import my own modules on webserver?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am developing a website and want to put some files on the server. The problem is that I can only import python modules ( e.g. "import os"), but somewhy, can not import my own modules:

test1.py:

```
import test2
```

test2.py:

```
print ("Content-type:text/html\n\n")
print ("<html>")
print ("<head>")
print ("<title>Error</title>")
print ("</head>")
print ("<body>")
print (" hello world 2")
print ("</body>")
print ("</html>")
```

If I click www.mywebsite.com/test2.py, then I recieve "hello world" on the screen.
However, if I click www.mywebsite.com/test1.py, I get "500 internal server error." I found out that it is some problem with not being able to import my modules.

p.s. since I am on a shared server, I can not changes sys path etc....

Here is a trace I got in errors.log:

```
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249] mod_python (pid=17816, interpreter='delekulator.co.il', phase='PythonHandler', handler='mod_python.cgihandler'): Application error
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249] ServerName: 'delekulator.co.il'
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249] DocumentRoot: '/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs'
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249] URI: '/test1.py'
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249] Location: None
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249] Directory: '/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/'
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249] Filename: '/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/test1.py'
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249] PathInfo: ''
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch\n    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target\n    result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target\n    result = object(arg)
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/cgihandler.py", line 96, in handler\n    imp.load_module(module_name, fd, path, desc)
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249]   File "/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/test1.py", line 1, in <module>\n    import test2
[Thu Jun 11 00:18:09 2015] [error] [client 85.65.174.249] ImportError: No module named test2
```

**In the last line, you can see that the server writes "ImportError: No module named test2"**

How can I fix it?

Comment: see what your error logs are printing ... on shared hosting you will need to search for `error.log` (being on shared hosting should not limit your ability to set your own path variable)

Comment: maybe you need a `__init__.py` file in your current directory so it is marked as a package?

Comment: @ Jörn Hees, please give more details, as I dont know what do you mean... thanks

Comment: Looks like you're using CGI? You **should** be deploying with uwsgi, fast_cgi, mod_wsgi or mod_proxy.

Comment: @Joran Beasley, here is my log entry: 85.65.174.249 - - [11/Jun/2015:00:09:13 +0300] "GET /test1.py HTTP/1.1" 500 1059 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"

Comment: @James Mills , please explain what do you mean? What should I do? please note, I can tart the .py script if I call it directly, however, the "import" does not work....

Comment: @Yura there should be a traceback of much more than what you posted ...

Comment: @Yura CGI is old, outdated and deprecated. Almost *no-one* deploys this way anymore; certainly not in production.

Comment: @Joran Beasley, I have edited my question and added what I ses in errors.log. In the last line, you can see that the server writes "ImportError: No module named test2"

Comment: @James Mills, I am pretty new to this and dont understand what you are saying... I am just using python to do some very basic operations... what do you mean? I just want to make the import work.

Comment: and test2.py is in the same folder?/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/  ? you could try adding `sys.path.append(".")` to the top of test1.py to try and ensure that the local directory is included on the path (I think this is always the case but meh)

Comment: @Joran Beasley, I have added import sys
sys.path.append(".") and it has worked!!! Thanks a lot! Can you pleae explain why didnt it work earlier...?

Comment: @Yura Please have a read of [mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/), [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/), [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) -- These are all modern, fast scalable ways of deploying web applications. In the simplest case you should be using a standard HTTP server for development but one of the above for deployment(s).

Answer (score 0):

From your description, your program did not found your own module, because you did not give your module's path. Now there are two methods to solve it:

Assume  your module's path is: `/srv/modules/xxxx.py` 
First you should import your module in your program: `import xxxx`

1. command line:Before you run your program with command line, give the path first. command:
   `export PYTHONPATH=/srv/modules`.Then run your program.
2. add two lines of codes in your program:

   `import sys
    sys.path.append("/srv/modules")`

Use any one way above, you should run your program success.I hope this can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Modules should be in the Python path or in the same directory where the executable is.

Then you do like usually

```
import test2

test2.some_function() # or whatever.
```

Comment: Really? Maybe, this can be helpful then? http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Comment: @ Alex Ivanov, I have checked permissions on both files and they are Read, Write Executable. What is www-data?

Comment: OK. Open file in Nautilus as root, go to Properties and check the boxes Read and Execute: Owner, Group, Others - http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/images/GnomeNautilus_CdromProperties.gif